# How to split a div element along with contents in it? (In a particular shape)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a web design with a unique shape. This is a simple coming soon template with the top left corner for info button and the bottom right corner for contact button. The green center area for the logo and other basic stuff.

[image: This is the basic shape]

The basic layout looks like this. I did this by creating 3 div elements. When it comes to the background color, this is fine. But the challenge is that I want those white pieces are like cut off from the green one. Something like this.

[image: This is what I have in my mind]

I also wish to have an output similar to the above image when it comes to playing a slideshow or Youtube/Vimeo video or custom video.

[image: Youtube Embed]

This is a Youtube video playing on the green area. But not the way I want it to be.

---

**I want the final output to look similar to this.** On the body background a pattern or a small animating pattern. Above that the cut-out layout and over that custom design another darker pattern to make it bit more attractive.

[image: Dream Output]

I know I am asking a lot here. But I never see any such design with a splitting of something from parent div (I did try overflow method, it didn't work or I missed something.) On top of this, the design should be responsive and the size of cutoffs (white triangles) must decrease in size with the very smaller displays.

I really need help from you guys. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Should be straight forward, [here's how](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) to create triangular shapes with CSS. Good luck !

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I've been working on this for months. (Because I am noob). But I did try those. In fact, I read those before. With the triangle shape, this works well. But for the green portion, nada. In the end, I used jquery.corner script for that particular shape. But still, none of it came out the way I want the website to look like.

Comment: @caramba Since you made the point. I will include the code snippet for so far I have done.